# What is the problem here with setTimeout and Closure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, settimeout

Firstly, I could not figure out the issue in this piece of code. But probably the issue has a place here.

As I could understand, the problem might be that the counter value is not updated after the button is clicked. The alert displays the value when the button was clicked, although during the delay of 2.5 seconds I clicked and increased the value of counter.

Am I right and if so, what should be fixed or added here?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Root() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  function handleAlertClick() {
    setTimeout(() => {
       alert(`You clicked ${count} times`)
      }, 2500)
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Column>
        <h4>Closures</h4>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(counter => counter + 1)}>
          Click me
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleAlertClick}>
          Show alert
        </button>
      </Column>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Root
```

Comment: *"As I could understand, the problem might be that the counter value is not updated after the button is clicked. "* Yes and no. `counter` is updated but `setTimeout` has already been invoked and thus refers to the "old" `counter` variable. Using refs is a simple way to solve this problem.

Comment: This might help to get a better understanding of closures: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196). The situation with a React component is pretty similar to the one with the loop; every rerender is basically a new iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem**

When the `setTimeout` is called, its callback function *closes* over the current value of the `count` in the current render of the `Root` component.

Before the timer expires, if you update the `count`, that causes a re-render of the component BUT the callback function of `setTimeout` still sees the value that was in *effect* when the `setTimeout` was called. This is the gist of the problem caused by the closure in your code.

Each render of the `Root` component has its own state, props, local functions defined inside the component; in short, each render of a compoent is separate from the ones before it.

State is constant within a particular render of a component; component can't see the updated state until it re-renders. Any timer set in the previous render will see the value that it *closed* over; it cannot see the updated state.

**Solution**

You can use the `useRef` hook to get rid of the problem caused due to closure.

You can update the ref every time the `Root` component is re-rendered. This allows us to save the latest value of `count` in the ref.

Once you have a ref, instead of passing `count` to `alert`, pass the ref. This ensures that alert always shows the latest value of `count`.

```js
function Root() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const countRef = React.useRef(count);

  // assign the latest value of "count" to "countRef"
  countRef.current = count;
  
  function handleAlertClick() {
    setTimeout(() => {
       alert(`You clicked ${countRef.current} times`)
      }, 2500)
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <h4>Closures</h4>
        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(counter => counter + 1)}>
          Click me
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleAlertClick}>
          Show alert
        </button>
      </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You don't even need to use `useEffect` here, you can just do `countRef.current = count;` directly.

Comment: Might worth noting that every render creates a new `handleAlertClick` function that captures the then current value of `counter`. `handleAlertClick` functions from older render passes are completely independent of `handleAlertClick` functions from new render passes.

Comment: @FelixKling right. Updated.